# what is scenario of using correlated and non correlated subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008, correlated-subquery

Today I came to know across a feature of SQL Server known as correlated query and noncorrelated query.Then the certain question comes in my mind:

What is difference between corelated and subquery in SQL Server? Is corleated subquery and non corelated subquery exist in SQL Server?

if yes the difference of this and where we should use one of them? Explain the concept with simple illustration if you can.

I would like to know it.

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Comment: You can accept answer if it helps you. Also the future visitors will be benefited with that.

Answer (score 6):

A **correlated subquery** is an inner subquery which is referenced by the main outer query such that the inner query is considered as being executed repeatedly.

**Example:**

```
USE DatabaseName;
GO
SELECT e.EmpID
FROM HumanResources.Emp e
WHERE e.ContactID IN
(
SELECT c.ContactID
FROM Person.Contact c
WHERE MONTH(c.ModifiedDate) = MONTH(e.ModifiedDate)
)
GO
```

A **noncorrelated subquery** is subquery that is independent of the outer query and it can executed on its own without relying on main outer query.

**Example:**

```
USE DatabaseName;
GO
SELECT e.EmpID
FROM HumanResources.Emp e
WHERE e.ContactID IN
(
SELECT c.ContactID
FROM Person.Contact c
WHERE c.Title = 'Mr.'
)
GO
```

More at the the [link.](http://weblogs.foxite.com/andykramek/2009/03/14/getting-to-grips-with-sql-sub-queries/)